# Having trouble in updating join model extra attributes in has_many through association - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, crud, has-many-through, join

I am still a learner of Rails, and am making a simulation game of Google Adwords for training usage. Inside the game (I may only explain the related part of this question), I have three models, **Adgroup** (called KeywordAdgroup in my code), **Keyword, AdgroupKeyword**, and also a Game model that has a game_id in it.

The relationship of the three models is a `has_many through:` assciation, which Adgroup has many Keywords through AdgroupKeyword, and Keyword has many Adgroups through AdgroupKeyword.

Now, I want to adopt a logic that every Keyword could only be added into single Adgroup of a particular game. So I added an extra attribute `game_id` to the join model - AdgroupKeyword, and adopt `validates_uniqueness_of :keyword_id, scope: :game_id` into this model.

However, I found that with the similar code, I can validate the uniqueness in Create using `.save` method, but I can't validate the uniqueness in Update using `.update(params)` method.

The major problem is that, with the similar code in `create` and `update`, the create one can `save` the `game_id` to the join model(AdgroupKeyword), where `update(params)` didn't save the `game_id` to the join model, which in the console, I can see that `update` didn't insert game_id into the record.

It will become something like `game_id: nil`:

```
#<AdgroupKeyword id: 180, keyword_id: 9, created_at: "2016-12-04 11:12:00", updated_at: "2016-12-04 11:12:00", keyword_adgroup_id: 77, game_id: nil>
```

But the save method did insert the game_id, which game_id is not nil when inserted using the save method.
Something like

```
#<AdgroupKeyword id: 174, keyword_id: 10, created_at: "2016-12-04 10:23:50", updated_at: "2016-12-04 10:23:50", keyword_adgroup_id: 77, game_id: 3>
```

The following is my code:

**keyword_adgroup.rb** (the model of Adgroup)

```
class KeywordAdgroup < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :keyword_campaign

  has_many :adgroup_keywords, inverse_of: :keyword_adgroup, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :keywords, through: :adgroup_keywords, source: :keyword
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :adgroup_keywords, allow_destroy: true

  ...

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :keywords

  ...

  ...
end
```

**keyword.rb**

```
class Keyword < ApplicationRecord
  ...

  ...

  has_many :keyword_adgroups, through: :adgroup_keywords
  has_many :adgroup_keywords

  ...
end
```

**adgroup_keyword.rb**(the join model)

```
class AdgroupKeyword < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :keyword_adgroup
  belongs_to :keyword

  validates_uniqueness_of :keyword_id, scope: :game_id

end
```

And majorly the relation would be built in the Adgroup controller.

**adgroups_controller.rb**

```
class Adwords::AdgroupsController < AdwordsController

  def index
    ...
  end

  def new
    @adgroup = KeywordAdgroup.new
  end

  def create
    @campaign = current_user.game.keyword_campaigns.find(params[:keyword_campaign_id])
    @adgroup = @campaign.keyword_adgroups.build(adgroup_params)
    @adgroup.game_id = @campaign.game_id
    @adgroup.adgroup_keywords.each do |join|
      join.game_id = @adgroup.game_id    
    end

    if @adgroup.save
      redirect_to new_adwords_ad_path(keyword_adgroup_id: @adgroup.id)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @adgroup = KeywordAdgroup.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @adgroup = KeywordAdgroup.find(params[:id])
    @campaign = @adgroup.keyword_campaign
    @adgroup.game_id = @campaign.game_id
    @joins = @adgroup.adgroup_keywords
    @joins.each do |join|
      join.game_id = @adgroup.game_id  
    end 
    if @adgroup.update(adgroup_params)

      redirect_to adwords_adgroups_path, notice: "Adgroup updated"
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  ...

  private
  def adgroup_params
    params.require(:keyword_adgroup).permit(:name, :activate, :bid, keyword_ids: [], adgroup_keywords_attributes: [:game_id])
  end

end
```

When choosing duplicate keyword in the same game in whatever adgroup, in "create", it will come to a rollback; in "update", it will just update the record with `game_id: nil`.

FYI, I am using Ruby 2.3.0, Rails 5.0.0, and using simpleform for creating and updating adgroup.

I know its a little bit messy, sorry about that and thanks for reading my words. Appreciate any suggestions. Have already spent several hours to fix it but really hopeless after a lot of different methods. Thought that it was some conceptual problem that I haven't figured out.

---

**Updated Information**

While checking the console, in "Create" method, it will come to:

```
  AdgroupKeyword Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "adgroup_keywords" WHERE "adgroup_keywords"."keyword_id" = ? AND "adgroup_keywords"."game_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["keyword_id", 14], ["game_id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Keyword Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "keywords" WHERE "keywords"."keyword" = ? AND ("keywords"."id" != ?) LIMIT ?  [["keyword", "Japan local trip"], ["id", 14], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  KeywordAdgroup Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "keyword_adgroups" WHERE "keyword_adgroups"."name" = ? AND "keyword_adgroups"."keyword_campaign_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["name", "3"], ["keyword_campaign_id", 36], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (2.3ms)  INSERT INTO "keyword_adgroups" ("name", "activate", "bid", "created_at", "updated_at", "keyword_campaign_id", "game_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "3"], ["activate", true], ["bid", #<BigDecimal:7fcaac52c320,'0.1E1',9(18)>], ["created_at", 2016-12-04 13:10:19 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-12-04 13:10:19 UTC], ["keyword_campaign_id", 36], ["game_id", 3]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "adgroup_keywords" ("keyword_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "keyword_adgroup_id", "game_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["keyword_id", 14], ["created_at", 2016-12-04 13:10:19 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-12-04 13:10:19 UTC], ["keyword_adgroup_id", 84], ["game_id", 3]]
  AdgroupKeyword Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "adgroup_keywords" WHERE "adgroup_keywords"."keyword_id" = ? AND ("adgroup_keywords"."id" != ?) AND "adgroup_keywords"."game_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["keyword_id", 14], ["id", 187], ["game_id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

In "Update" method, it will come to:

```
  AdgroupKeyword Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "adgroup_keywords" WHERE "adgroup_keywords"."keyword_id" = ? AND "adgroup_keywords"."game_id" IS NULL LIMIT ?  [["keyword_id", 17], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (2.0ms)  INSERT INTO "adgroup_keywords" ("keyword_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "keyword_adgroup_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["keyword_id", 17], ["created_at", 2016-12-04 13:07:03 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-12-04 13:07:03 UTC], ["keyword_adgroup_id", 82]]
  AdgroupKeyword Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "adgroup_keywords" WHERE "adgroup_keywords"."keyword_id" = ? AND ("adgroup_keywords"."id" != ?) AND "adgroup_keywords"."game_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["keyword_id", 11], ["id", 185], ["game_id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to run this block **after** the `#update` call (inside the `if` block)?

```
@adgroup.reload

@adgroup.adgroup_keywords.each do |join|
  join.update(:game_id, @adgroup.game_id)
end
```

Comment: Oh, you are right, coz in my "create", it needed a first step on choosing the keyword campaign, hence, pass the campaign_id and create the adgroup. But why and how would it affect my "update" method? Big thanks!

Comment: I just updated my answer -- can you check if its actually passing `game_id` value?

Comment: Thanks, I have updated some information in the bottom. I have tried to remove it from the permitted params before but with no luck. Feel confused for hours.

Comment: Thank you. Can you print the `adgroup_params` just before the `#update` call?

Comment: I thought about something like: I have set game_id for each adgroup_keyword(join model) of the adgroup, but @adgroup.save do know to save the game_id into database; @adgroup.update(adgroup_params) don't know to save the game_id into database. But how should I fix it?

Comment: Oops, sorry for late. I just use puts adgroup_params.inspect and it comes out: <ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"2", "bid"=>"1.0", "keyword_ids"=>["", "13", "17"]} permitted: true>

Comment: Ok, now I'm really understanding the problem... just updated my answer, can you try again?

Comment: Have tried it. It still insert without game_id, but after inserting the join model, it will cause some rollback due to the join.update(game_id: @adgroup.gam_id). I have tried to do it before the loop, but still insert without game_id. I really can't understand why.

Comment: Can you try to make a `@adgroup.reload` before the loop? It should be after the `update`.

Comment: Still, the program insert all the records without game_id during @adgroup.update(adadgroup_params) before the reload is done, and doing rollback during join.update. How could I update adgroup_keyword(the join model) with game_id updating at the same time? Is there no way for updating but creating the extra attribute of join model?