# The standard way to update extra attribute of join model - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, crud

here comes to the newbie of rails again.

Actually I have asked a similar question in this:[Having trouble in updating join model extra attributes in has_many through association - Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40958416/having-trouble-in-updating-join-model-extra-attributes-in-has-many-through-assoc), but thought that I have asked in a wrong direction and a complicated way, so would like to open a new question that ask in a simpler and more precise way.

Would like to know when I have an extra attribute in the join model of `has_many through:`, **what is the standard way to save and update the extra attribute of the join model**. Below is just an example and what I have tried:

In a `Forum`, A `User` has many `Group`; A `Group` has many `User`, through `GroupUser`.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :group_users
    has_many :groups, through: :group_users
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :forum

    has_many :group_users
    has_many :users, through: :group_users
end

class GroupUser < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :group
    belongs_to :user
end

class Forum < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :groups
end
```

Due to some reason, I may want to add an extra attribute `forum_id`to the join model`GroupUser`so it becomes like:

[UML diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2cRg.png)

What would be the correct way to do the `create` and `update` in the controller?

I have tried something like:

```
def create
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
    @group = @forum.groups.build(group_params)
    @group.group_users.each do |join|
        join.forum_id = @group.forum_id
    end
    @group.save
end

def update
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
    @group.group_users.each do |join|
        join.forum_id = @group.forum_id
    end
    @group.update(group_params)
end

private
def group_params
    params.require(:group).permit(:name, user_ids: [])
end
```

I can save the `forum_id` in the `create`; however, the `forum_id` will be nil when doing an `update` in the association. It has bordered me for more than twenty hours already, I really want to know the **standard way to save and update the extra attribute of the join model**.

Thanks for reading my words. Appreciate any comments. Every suggestion will alleviate my headache right now. Thanks.

---

**Updated 10:17AM +8, 7 Dec**

I have tried the `accepted_nested_attributes_for` solution with no luck, which I can still insert the `forum_id` in `save`, but still not inserting `forum_id` in `update`, which the record updated will get a `forum_id: nil`

The changes is as following:

Model:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :forum

  has_many :group_users, inverse_of: :group
  has_many :users, through: :group_users

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :group_users
end
```

Controller:

```
def group_params
    params.require(:group).permit(:name, user_ids: [], group_users_attributes: [:id, :forum_id])
end
```

I have actually created a project which you can download here: https://github.com/kan1011/rails-101-demo (If you want to run it, you need to create the first forum in rails c, by `f = Forum.new` and `f.save`)

---

**Updated 12:53pm +8, 8/12/2016**

Have tried to use `save` instead of `update(params)`, but it didn't update at all, which the record will be the same after submit the update form.

Have tried to use `puts params.inspect` and `puts group_params.inspect`, and it comes out the following:

*params*

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"s8l+wWzTci7hD1AoyLN9sIjFu296ooU0VwWgCFIP4yvJaR7I3HS9E3ja4VXcFQv1QadyeJspef3dBD1XzVaF+Q==", "group"=>{"name"=>"fff", "user_ids"=>["", "1", "2", "3"]}, "commit"=>"Submit", "id"=>"8"}
```

"✓", "_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"s8l+wWzTci7hD1AoyLN9sIjFu296ooU0VwWgCFIP4yvJaR7I3HS9E3ja4VXcFQv1QadyeJspef3dBD1XzVaF+Q==", "group"=>{"name"=>"fff", "user_ids"=>["", "1", "2", "3"]}, "commit"=>"Submit", "controller"=>"groups", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"8"} permitted: false>

*group_params*

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"fff", "user_ids"=>["", "1", "2", "3"]} permitted: true>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm only making a guess here, but I think you have to add

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :group_users
```

on your group model. Also, believe you have to add the permited params to your controller. Something like:

```
params.require(:group).permit(:name, user_ids: [], group_users_attributes: [:id, :attribute1, :attribute2, :_destroy])
```

That's kinda how I do that. In that case, `:_destroy` attribute is only needed if you're using cocoon gem. Replace attribute1, attribute2 for the ones that you wanna update. In that case, I believe it's only `forum_id`.

Hope this helps you someway...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Have tried and updated in the question, but with no luck..., I thought the critical point may be the difference of #save and #update(params). Do you have any thought about this? Big thanks.

Comment: well, have you tried to call save instead of update? save command can be used for updating as well...

Comment: Also, try to debug on your update action what is coming from the group_params (logger.debug group_params.to_h). I believe that forum_id is coming nil. Also, debug all params, like logger.debug params.to_unsafe_h (that way it shows all params, ignoring strong params), so we can see better if the problem is on the params being passed to update or if the values are not coming from the form...

Comment: have tried #save, but it didn't update the record. And for the debug, I have read some doc about it but not really understand how to use it. I have used puts params.inspect and puts group_params.inspect instead, and updated in the question. Again, million thanks for your help.